# delete repetitious numbers from a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have written the following code to do two things:

1. to create a list of unique four-digit numbers using 2, 5, 7, and 9.
2. to filter the above list by removing the numbers in which a digit is repeated (e.g., 2592).

The program seems to work fine with the exception that it fails to remove the numbers in which the last two digits are identical, such as 2599, or 9255.

Here is the code (sorry if it's not well written; I'm an absolute beginner still experimenting with loops).

```py
#Please write a program producing four-digit numbers using  2,5,7,9
# In once case, repetition is allowed, in the other it's not.
#The answer to the first part of the question:
list= []
x=2222
index=0
while 2222<=x<=9999:
    numList = [int(digit) for digit in str(x)]

    for t in range(len(numList)):
        k=int(numList[t])
        if k!=2 and k!=5 and k!=7 and k!=9:
            t-=1
            break

    if t==3:
        list.insert(index,x)
        index+=1
    x+=1

print("There are {} numbers in total with repetition:".format(len(list)))
print((list))

# The answer to the second part of the question:
list1=list.copy()
for t in range (len(list)):
    f=0
    item=list[t]
    digit_List = [int(digit) for digit in str(item)]
    for y in range(len(digit_List)-1):
        if f==1:
            break
        p=int(digit_List[0])
        for z in range (1,len(digit_List)):
            if p==digit_List[z]:
                f=1
                break
        if len(digit_List)>2:
            digit_List.pop(y)
    if f>0:
        list1.remove(item)
print("There are {} numbers in total without repetition:".format(len(list1)))
print(list1)
```

It would be highly appreciated if you could help me sort it out. I run the code in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `list` as a variable name, it coincides with the Python type.

The issue isn't just for the last two digits, in longer numbers it will fail for way more numbers, like 13225. The problem is here:

```
for y in range(len(digit_List)-1):
    ...
    if len(digit_List)>2:
        digit_List.pop(y)
```

You are altering `digit_List` constantly. Let's say `digit_List` is originally `[1, 3, 2, 2]`.

When `y` is 0, you pop index 0, now `digit_List` is `[3, 2, 2]`.

When `y` is 1, you pop index 1. 3 used to be index 1 of the original list, but not now, since you already removed an element. Remember, you are doing the operation on the current list, not the original list. You remove the second item, 2. Now the list is `[3, 2]`. And obviously, no duplicates exist anymore.

You should write `digit_List.pop(0)` instead, as you want to be popping the first item in the list each time.

To be frank, you shouldn't be removing the digits as you go along. When you're constantly altering stuff, things get tricky, making it easy to make the mistake you made. Instead, just have two pointers iterate over the list.

```
for i in range(len(digit_List)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(digit_List)):
        if digit_List[i] == digit_List[j]:
            # Duplicate digits identified
```